# Find the count of not null values in a JSON using lodash

Tags: node.js, lodash

I have a JSON response like

```js
let obj = [
  {
    id: 1,
    amount: null,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    amount: 123,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    amount: null,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    amount: null,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    amount: 100,
  },
];
```

I need to find the count of not null values present in the above JSON response using lodash function.

I had done using the normal way in my code below

```js
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  if (obj[i]['amount'] != null) {
    count++;
  }
}
console.log(count);
```

Can anyone give an idea of how to do the same using lodash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_.sumBy()` and return 1 if not falsy (`null` or 0):

```js
const obj = [{"id":1,"amount":null},{"id":2,"amount":123},{"id":3,"amount":null},{"id":4,"amount":null},{"id":5,"amount":100}]

const result = _.sumBy(obj, ({ amount }) => amount ? 1 : 0)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Another option is to use `_.countBy()` to count items with `amount` value of `null` or not, and take the `'false'` value:

```js
const obj = [{"id":1,"amount":null},{"id":2,"amount":123},{"id":3,"amount":null},{"id":4,"amount":null},{"id":5,"amount":100}]

const result = _.countBy(obj, ({ amount }) => _.isNull(amount))['false']

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use the lodash [reduce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#reduce) function, we could also use [filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter), either will get you the result you require:

```js
const obj = [ { "id": 1, "amount": null }, { "id": 2, "amount": 123 }, { "id": 3, "amount": null }, { "id": 4, "amount": null }, { "id": 5, "amount": 100 } ]

let count = _.reduce(obj, (sum, row) => row.amount !== null ? sum + 1: sum, 0);
console.log("Count using _.reduce:", count);

count = _.filter(obj, (row) => row.amount !== null).length;
console.log("Count using _.filter:", count);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like in vanilla JavaScript, I think that also for lodash using [`reduce()`](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#reduce) is the best approach:

```js
const obj = [{
  "id": 1,
  "amount": null
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "amount": 123
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "amount": null
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "amount": null
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "amount": 100
}];

const count = _.reduce(obj, ((a, {amount}) => a + (amount != null ? 1 : 0)), 0);

console.log(count);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You could use filter-like methods as well, but you would incur the additional overhead of creating the filtered array.

There's really no need to use lodash for this though:

```js
const obj = [{
  "id": 1,
  "amount": null
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "amount": 123
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "amount": null
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "amount": null
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "amount": 100
}];

const count = obj.reduce(((a, {amount}) => a + (amount != null ? 1 : 0)), 0);

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need lodash here, everything can be done easily using vanilla JavaScript. All you need to do is to filter out only values that have the amount and then find array length.

```js
const obj = [
  {
    id: 1,
    amount: null,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    amount: 123,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    amount: null,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    amount: null,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    amount: 100,
  },
];


const result = obj.filter((x) => x.amount !== null).length

console.log(result);
```